# Ruby on rails rspec destroy count fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, destroy

I've written some tests for simple application. I'm having problem with #destroy method in my authors_controller. As I've done this from some tutorials (many sources shows similar approach) I guess it should work, but such error occurs:

`Failure/Error: expect { delete :destroy, id: author.id }.to change(Author, :count).by(-1) expected #count to have changed by -1, but was changed by 0`

Here's my code:

author_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'                        

describe AuthorsController do                 
  let(:author) { FactoryGirl.create(:author) }

  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do                                                                            
    it 'deletes author' do                                                      
      expect { delete :destroy, id: author.id }.to change(Author, :count).by(-1)
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

authors_controller.rb

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
def show
@author = Author.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @author = Author.new
end

def create
  @author = Author.new(author_params)
  if @author.save
    redirect_to @author
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])

  if @author.update(author_params)
    redirect_to @author
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @author = Author.find(params[:id])
  @author.books.each do |book|
  book.destroy if book.authors.count == 1
  end
  @author.destroy
  redirect_to authors_path
end

def index
  @author = Author.all
end

private

  def author_params
    params.require(:author).permit(:name, :surname, book_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `let` call is not made until the first time you mention the variable, as it's lazy evaluation. This means that within your `expect` block, you are both creating and destroying the record, leading to an overall change of 0.

Either create the `author` outside of the block:

```
describe AuthorsController do                 
  let(:author) { FactoryGirl.create(:author) }

  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do   
    author                                                                         
    it 'deletes author' do                                                      
      expect { delete :destroy, id: author.id }.to change(Author, :count).by(-1)
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

Or, tell the `let` block not to evaluate lazily by using `let!`:

```
describe AuthorsController do                 
  let!(:author) { FactoryGirl.create(:author) }

  describe 'DELETE #destroy' do                                                                            
    it 'deletes author' do                                                      
      expect { delete :destroy, id: author.id }.to change(Author, :count).by(-1)
    end                                                                         
  end                                                                           
end
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for answering and explanation. I've found such solution and it worked, but just didn't know why is it so.

Comment: No problem. If this works, do please mark it as the accepted answer so that the next person knows.

Comment: Had to wait - probably a lot of guys in my office uses stack :)